# bootstrap "center-block"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to make a UI like the following：

```
------------------------------------------------
|                                               |
|    div-outside                                |
|         ----------------------------          |
|         |                          |          |
|         |                          |          |
|         |        div-inside        |          |
|         |                          |          |
|         |                          |          |
|         ----------------------------          |
|                                               |
|                                               |
-------------------------------------------------
```

The code is:

```
   <div id="app-layout-body" class="container-fluid body-content">
     <div id="div-register" class="center-block"     style="width:350px;margin-top:80px;">
      ....
    </div>
   </div>
```

To make the inner div center at the outer div, I'm using class="center-block". It works well if the screen is wider than a specific number, such as 1000px, but if the screen width is not big enough, the inner div will be adjacent to the right of outer div:

```
----------------------------------------
|                                       |
|    div-outside                        |
|         ----------------------------  |
|         |                          |  |
|         |                          |  |
| left    |        div-inside        |  |
| margin  |                          |  |
|         |                          |  |
|         ----------------------------  |
|                                       |
|                                       |
-----------------------------------------
```

With Chrome's developer tool, I found that when the inner div is not centered, the left margin will be a fixed number (it seems have a lower bound). But when the screen's width is varying above the boundary value, the left margin number will vary according to the width thus making the inner div always centered. In fact, when the inner div is not horizontally centered, if I manually adjust the left margin number, then the inner div will be centered.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is working. The problem is that the layout does not work if the screen width is **smaller** than 350px, because you have chosen a **fixed** **width**.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oed8uqct/)

If the `<div>` should center all the time, use **cols** and **offset**:

```
<div id="app-layout-body" class="container-fluid body-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="div-register" class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            center with offset
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example offset](http://jsfiddle.net/1tc53cu1/)

More information about [Bootstrap's grid offsetting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).

Comment: Thank you Amwiom for your reply! In fact, when the screen's width is 768 (iPad in portrait mode 768*1024), then inner div is off center already.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's `.center-block` contains nothing more than

```
.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

There should be something else which is adding some other rules to your container. From the Inspector, try to check the CSS (fixed left margin) which you are talking about is getting added from which file.

Comment: Thank you Rupesh Jain. Maybe you are right, but to find out where the fixed left margin come from is a challenging. I'll try to get it done.

Comment: It can be found out using the Chrome/FF Dev tools.Use the computed styles tab to find what is getting finally applied. Then you can trace it out. You will get a magnifier/caret icon when you hover on the rule in the Computed styles tab. Comment back if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```css
#app-layout-body {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
#div-register {
  border: 5px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div id="app-layout-body">
    <div id="div-register"><strong>I'm a centered Div inside another centered Div..</strong>
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
        up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
        Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a
        line in section 1.10.32.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you vanburenx, I tried your code, but it still does not work. After applying your code, the inner div seems not horizontally centered any more.

Comment: If you can post any additional code you have that is interacting with your example that would be best as to see what is actively happen.

Comment: Thank you vanburenx! The complete code is too long. I will crop the related part and post it here after an hour or two.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution yet?

Comment: I was bogged down by other things these two days. :(  The problem is still not solved. If i can make some progress i will publish the solution here. thank you very much for your concern, vanburenx!

Comment: Understandable and if you get a chance to put up the rest of the related code let me know.